# Geocoder ordering by mix of distance and age

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, geocoding

I'm using [Geocoder](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder) to geocode a bunch of projects, and ideally what I'd like to do is sort the geocoded projects from a mix of proximity and age. Being able to do something like `ORDER BY distance * ln(created_at) ASC` would be ideal, but since distance is an alias, that query fails (no aliases allowed in order clauses). Any thoughts on a workaround?

I'm using Rails.

Thanks!

Comment: No solution, but you can order by an alias.  You can't order by an alias if that alias is used in an expression.  From what I know of geocoder, you'd have to modify the gem to allow this.

Comment: @PhilipHallstrom any alternatives?